# Weird rendering issues on Android Wear

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Wear watch face and I am getting a very unusual output. There is a mysterious circle area where some subviews are not fully rendered. The funny thing is I never add a circle to the view.

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot of the watch face on a moto 360 emulator]

The weird thing is the clock hands are outputted just fine, they are added to the view first. Here is a snippit of the code that draws the lines:

```
for(int i=1; i<=60; i++) {
       int seconds = i;
       int radius = (screenWidth / 2);
       int centre = (screenWidth / 2);
       int totalLimit = 60;
       int currentValue = seconds;
       int theta = (360 / totalLimit) * currentValue;

       double x = centre + radius * Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180);
       double y = centre + radius * Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180);

       float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - centre, y - centre));
       if (angle < 0) {
           angle += 360;
       }
       if (angle > 180)
           angle -= 180;
       else
           angle += 180;


       View view = new View(this);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1, radius);
       params.leftMargin = (int)x;
       params.topMargin = (int)y;
       view.setPivotX(0);
       view.setPivotY(0);
       view.setRotation(-angle);
       view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       mWatchView.addView(view, params);

       views.add(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK So instead on drawing the lines from inside out, I now draw them from outside in. This fixes this problem.

```
params.leftMargin = (int)(screenWidth-x);
params.topMargin = (int)(screenWidth-y);
```

Also changed the radius depending on the length of line I wanted

```
int length = 15;
int width = 1;
if (i == 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60) {
    length = 35;
    width = 2;
}
if (i == 5 || i == 15 || i == 25 || i == 35 || i == 45 || i == 55) {
   length = 25;
   width = 2;
}
int seconds = i;
int radius = (screenWidth / 2)-length;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the outer start points and the angles correctly, but what happens with the lengths? Check the margins!

Comment: Thanks. Any tips of how I can add a view at x,y and then rotate it, but still retain its length?